# PHP: Как сделать поиск на соответствие значению в массиве?

Tags: php, массивы, поиск

Есть массив, получаемый из файла с расширением .csv

```
$data = file("file.csv");
```

И есть текст, получаемый из инпута через глобальный массив $_POST

```
$text = $_POST['text'];
```

Нужно сделать поиск на соответствие текста значению в массиве. Пробовал так:

```
if (in_array($text, $data)) {
  echo "Совпадение найдено";
}
else {
  echo "Совпадений не найдено";
}
```

Совпадений почему-то не находит. Пробовал даже так:

```
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
  if($text == $value) {
    echo "Совпадение найдено";
  }
  else {
    echo "Совпадений не найдено";
  }
}
```

Всё равно ничего не находит (хотя $text специально ввожу идентичный одному из значений массива).

В чём может быть проблема? Как осуществить поиск?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Эта особенность описана в [мануале](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php):

> Each line in the resulting array will include the line ending, unless FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES is used

При вызове `file` с дефолтными флагами в массиве у вас будут строки, включающие символы перевода строк. А с формы поле `input` идёт без перевода строки. Соответственно, это бинарно различные строки и совпадений нет.

Для того, чтобы символа перевода строки не включались в элементы массива есть отдельный флаг `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES`. Скорей всего пустые строки вам тоже не нужны (их можно сразу пропускать флагом `FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES`), так что получается

```
$data = file("file.csv", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
```

Answer (score 2):

Внимательно ознакомьтесь с документаций к используемой функции `file()`.

> Возвращает файл в виде массива. Каждый элемент массива соответствует строке файла, **с символами новой строки включительно**.

так что вы, вероятно, сравниваете строку `abc` со строкой файла `abc\n`, в итоге получаете соответствующий результат.
Вероятно, при поиске последней строки файла  результат будет положительный, т.к. там не будет символа `\n`.