# Не работает in_array()

Tags: php

Подскажите почему не работает..

```
$arrayBanIP = file ('blacklist.txt');
// проверяем наличие IP пользователя в списке заблокированнный

if(in_array($ipUser, $arrayBanIP)){

    // если заблокирован, то останавливаем скрипт и выводим сообщение
    header('Location: /404');
    exit();

}
```

В итоге ничего не происходит.. Хотя через print_r выводит все что нужно, и переменные совпадают, в чем магия?

Comment: А массив у Вас как выглядит? `['192.168.0.1' , '192.168.0.2']` ?

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/578097/203622 Магия в мануале и переводе строки.

Answer (score 2):

В вызове **file()** нужно добавить дополнительные флаги. Иначе, у Вас строки в массиве будут вместе с символами перевода строк.

```
$arrayBanIP = file ('blacklist.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
```